# Shopify not executing jQuery (Geolocation script)

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm trying to use a jQuery script to alter the contact page layout based on the user's location. It works as expected in JSbin, but when ported to Shopify it's simply not working.

There's nothing in the console to suggest there's a conflict.

Does anyone have any ideas why it's not working?

EDIT: updated snippet to working solution. The IP service being called did not allow HTTPS requests, I switched to a different one and now it is working on Shopify as intended.

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://freegeoip.app/json/",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(json) {
    if (json.country_code === "GB") {
        alert('you are in the UK'); 
  }
  }      
});
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: How **exactly** is that snipped called? Do you use some kind of event handler?

Comment: I just have it in script tags.

Comment: Can you share the full and exact code for that? Have you checked in your browser's developer console whether the request is executed?

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: @LawrenceAmes, based on your updated code, please see my answer. You need to wrap that code in `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the like and info provided in the comments, I was able to run the code in your site's context. The code is executing successfully, but your API provider is prohibiting the action that you're trying to do based on your subscription level. See the error, below.

[image]

The [API docs](https://ipstack.com/documentation) say it a bit differently - `The current subscription plan does not support this API endpoint.`

Comment: I switched from IPstack to a different service and now it is working as intended on the live store. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @LawrenceAmes, my pleasure. Be sure to vote my answer up and mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!